# Is there a word or expression which defines a text or sentence which does not explain all of its terms?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I think I summed it up in the title, but to be more specific, check this sentence:

> "ECM is an umbrella term covering document management, web content
>   management, search, collaboration, records management, digital asset
>   management (DAM), work-flow management, capture and scanning."

In this case, "collaboration", "DAM", "work-flow management" are all very generic terms which can give us an idea about what is being explained, but if you don't know the specific usage of these terms, you'll end up clueless about what really is an ECM.

This simpler sentence, instead, is more "self-containing":

> "ECM is a formalized means of organizing and storing an organization's
>   documents, and other content, that relate to the organization's
>   processes."

In short, is there a word or expression which defines a text full of (difficult or not) words, expressions and acronyms which the reader cannot understand without further information about the subject?

Comment: I'm afraid I think this is Too Broad, since there are many ways to describe such text. You might consider *recondite, obscure, abstruse, arcane, esoteric, recherché,* etc.

Comment: There is *bombastic* (high sounding, but containing little actual meaning).

Comment: DAM is a generic term?  Damn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that falls under the category of ***"jargon"*** where only an industry insider would know what each acronym represented.

For the purpose of explanation or definition, as in your example, jargon should be avoided.

> **From the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary**:
>
> Jar-gon: noun
>
> 2:  the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group

Comment: Thanks! I assume I could go with `jargonistic` as an adjective, as in: `This article is too jargonistic`, right?

Comment: I never thought of "jargonistic" but that would work.  I'd also probably say that it's "jargon-heavy" or "jargon-filled".

Comment: I have heard of jingo-istic, but not in this sense. Kristina's terms seem fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

`Ambiguous` seems like the word that you are looking for here.  From m-w.com:

> **am·big·u·ous**
>
> adjective \am-ˈbi-gyə-wəs\
>
> : able to be understood in more than one way : having more than one possible meaning
>
> : not expressed or understood clearly

It's not that the technical words are inappropriate in this context, it's simply that they need further explanation, in order to make sure that the intent of their meaning is clear.